# jVectorMap Issue while loading ajax data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jvectormap

I'm trying to show data from visitors inside a map created using jvectormap plugin.

This is driving me crazy, i can not load the data through ajax, if i put the data manually it works.

So far i have this:

map.php

```
$datos = array();
$link->set_charset("utf8");
$sql = $link->query("SELECT SUM(ID) as visitors, state FROM visitors WHERE state != '' GROUP BY state");
while($row = $sql->fetch_row()){
    $ss = $link->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE state = '".$row[1]."'");
    $rr = $ss->fetch_row();
    $datos[] = array("ccode" => $rr[2], "visits" => $row[0]);
}
$data = array("countries" => $datos);
echo json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This returns the following data:

```
{"countries":[{"ccode":"VE-A","visits":81},{"ccode":"VE-L","visits":24}]}
```

Now the function to load the map:

```
function cargaMapa(){
        //jvectormap data
    $.post("ajax/map.php",{},function(mapa){
        var dataC = eval(mapa);
        //var dataC = {"countries":[{"ccode":"VE-A","visits":81},{"ccode":"VE-L","visits":24}]};
        var countryData = []; 
        //for each country, set the code and value
        $.each(dataC.countries, function() {
            countryData[this.ccode] = this.visits;
            console.log("Estado: "+this.ccode+" Visitas: "+this.visits);
        });
        //World map by jvectormap
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({
            map: 've_mill_en',
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            regionStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: '#e4e4e4',
                    "fill-opacity": 1,
                    stroke: 'none',
                    "stroke-width": 0,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                }
            },
            series: {
                regions: [{
                        values: countryData,
                        scale: ["#3c8dbc", "#2D79A6"], //['#3E5E6B', '#A6BAC2'],
                        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                    }]
            },
            onRegionLabelShow: function(e, el, code) {
                //search through dataC to find the selected country by it's code
                var country = $.grep(dataC.countries, function(obj, index) {
                    return obj.ccode == code;
                })[0]; //snag the first one
                //only if selected country was found in dataC
                if (country != undefined) { 
                    el.html(el.html() + ': ' + country.ccode + country.visits + ' visitas');
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

As you can see in the function i have the var dataC, if i load in there the array coming from map.php it gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` but if copy and paste the result of map.php into the var dataC it works pretty good.

How can i solve this?

I appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just changed `$.post` for `$.getJSON` and the magic began